# Javascript deleting elements from a list

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, appendchild

I hope someone can help me with my problem here. I've got a function which basically creates a list with user given inputs. 
For example: The user gives the input `apples` and the function adds `apples` to a `<ul>` list.

Now I have a question regarding deleting the inputs.
For example: I want to delete the `apples` child from the list. This should happen in an input field when the user types in `apples`.

How can I do this?

Comment: If possible, can you give a [mcve] using the snippet tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery and remove the item from the list by running on the list with `each()` and remove it with `remove()`, here is an example:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() { 
  var value = $('input').val() 

  $('ul li').each(function(index, li) {
    var item = $(li); 
    if(item.text() == value){
        item.remove()
    }

  }); 
});
```

you can check it on: https://jsfiddle.net/pww9uea8/

you can check more about [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) from jQuery documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I implemented your code and now everything works just fine! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make something like this:

```
const inputFromValue;    
const elemForDelete = Array.from(document.getElementById("myUL").children)
.find(child => child.innerText == inputFromValue ))
```

Find text of element compare with your input value and remove this element from "myUL".